# AWS API Gateway limits of Routes and Integrations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

AWS API Gateway has a [limit of 300 routes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html), which can be increased by contacting AWS, but it also has a limit of 300 integrations that **cannot** be increased.

My understanding is that every route must have an Integration defined as one of these options:

- Lambda Function
- HTTP
- Mock
- AWS Service
- VPC Link

Not having an integration set for a route is not an option.

Given that, what's the point of requesting more than 300 routes if I can't have more than 300 integrations?

I must be misinterpreting what "Integration" means in this context, what else could it mean?

Comment: I may be wrong but could you use the same integration for multiple routes? I don't know why or a use case that isn't just wildcard forwarding but perhaps there is a reason someone would use two explicitly different routes to the same integration?

Comment: I have around 120 endpoints atm mapped to 11 Lambdas but it's not clear if they count as 120 or 11 integrations. Hopefully it's the latter, but there's no easy way to test. I may have to contact AWS to increase that soft limit and try mapping 301 routes to 1 Lambda to see what happens, if I can't get an answer here.

Comment: Either that or try something like the CDK to deploy an app gateway with two endpoints mapped to the same integration. That way in cloud formation you'll be able to see how many unique resources are used

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that increasing the limit of Routes **allowed me to create more than 300 endpoints with Integrations mapping to the same Lambda function**.

I didn't try more than 300 different Lambdas, but for the purpose of this question this at least confirms that multiple mappings to the same Lambda are not counting toward this limit of 300 "Integrations".